# AngularJS ng-repeat an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an object as the scope. The object looks like this:
[image: object]

And my controller looks like this:

```
    module.controller('ActiveController', ['$scope','$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/order/?format=json'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                console.log("OK Respone");
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.orders = response.data;
              }, function errorCallback(response) {

                console.log("NO Response");
        });
 }]);
```

In the browser console, the object looks like this:

[image: Object in console]

I would like some help to loop out and display whole the object in the .html file. My current code that does not work is currently looking like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ActiveController">
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <p>{{ order.id }}</p>
    <p>{{ order.created }}</p>     
</div>
</div>
```

I don't think I need to show my "main" .html file, so I'm not posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the controller. Try saving `objects` in `$scope.orders`

```
$scope.orders = response.data.objects;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, will accept when the time limit is over :)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this in the view and the controller as well:

**In View as:**

```
<div ng-controller="ActiveController">
  <div ng-repeat="order in orders.objects"> <!-- note the orders.objects -->
    <p>{{ order.id }}</p>
    <p>{{ order.created }}</p>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**In Controller as**

```
$scope.orders = response.data.objects;
```

As rightly suggested by @ddepablo.
It will work fine.